# Calling properties from the list properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to assign a value for the TechDomain competency field. But, I am having an issue.

```cs
public record TechDomain{
   public string Id { get; set;}
   public List<Competency> competency { get; set;}
}

public record Competency{
   public string name { get; set;}
   public string add { get; set;}
}

var record = new TechDomain();
record.competency.name = "Sample 1";
```

It says that the 'name' is not accessible in record.competency. what is missing in my code?

Thank you.

Comment: `TechDomain.competency` is of type `List<Compentency` - and `List<T>` doesn't have a `name` field or property. (This is where if you'd named it `Compentencies`, the mistake would have been more obvious - trying to assign a name to something that's clearly plural is more obviously a mistake.)

Comment: To think of it another way: what do you want to happen if the list has no elements? Or if it has more than one element?

Answer (score 0):

When you do `record.competency` you access to the `competency` attribute, wich is of type `List<Competency>`. You can't call `name` on a list. First you have to take one element of your list, for example `record.competency[0].name`, assuming your list is not empty.